# how to open background buffers in new tab without influence current window?

Tags: vim

I open a bunch of files by `vim *.html *.css *.js`, and I want to know how to open those targeted files in background buffers without mess up current window?

I tried to use vsplit, then `"buf <buffer-number-I-want-to-open>`, then C-w T. But I found it's way to tedious.

So is there a clear way to do that? thanks!

Comment: `:help :next` and scroll around.

Comment: But :next won't maintain current window, I want to leave current window untouched ;-)

Comment: You can come back to the current window later.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch vim by `vim *.html *.css *.js`, the argument would be loaded into your vim **argument list**.

you can get the list it by `args:`. 
And you can use `:next`, `:previous`, `first`, `last`, to traverse them.

if you want to open them all as tab?

you can use **argdo**: **`argdo tab split`**. this will dispatch a `tab split` command to each element in the arglist.

see: 
:help :args
:help :argdo
:help :tab

Answer (score -1):

you can `:tabnew` then use `:next` or `buffer + <num>` to open background buffers. but it will introduce a `NO NAME` buffer.

a neater way is to use **CtrlP**'s buffer view, then press `<Ctrl-t>` and you will have it.

--

plugin [Ctrl-P](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim) can perfectly achieve this, if you want to save your time, you can stick with it.

For example, suppose you have 3 buffers, where you are in buffer 1 and 2 more buffers are in background.

```
:ls
1 %a  index.html
2     style.css
3 h   script.js
```

Assume that you want to open buffer `3 script.js`

1. open **CtrlP**,
2. switch to `buf` view, and choose the buffer your want to open
3. then press `<C-t>`, you would be able to open the buffers in new tab

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem perfectly!   In addition,  is there a way to open all the buffers on new tab but not just chosen one?